# Filter (stop) rxjs observable if form invalid

Tags: angular, rxjs

Should be quite a simple thing but I'm struggling to get my head around this. I just wish to prevent the observable continuing if the form is invalid. Any ideas?

```
this.subscription2 = this.myForm.valueChanges.pipe(
        map(params => params['invalid']),
        filter(invalid => !!invalid),
        debounceTime(1000)).subscribe(x => {

        //Logic here

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the form is invalid, you don't listen to a property of it, but to the form itself.

```js
this.subscription2 = this.myForm.valueChanges.pipe(
        filter(invalid => this.myForm.valid),
        debounceTime(1000)).subscribe(x => {

        //Logic here

});
```